# Automatically creating hundreds of .fla files, who gather external ressources

Tags: python, flash, actionscript, jsfl

I'm looking to create a lot of .fla files automatically but I'm not sure where to start.
This is for an internal tool for a cartoon studio, they work with Flash CC, each file Flash is a scene for an episode (scene1, scene 2, scene 3 ...) and in each file, we have a .flv from the scene, a .wav, a .jpg, and a specific template (folder and layers organisations and few stuff like a safe frame etc)
Every external elements are in external folders

- a folder with .flv
- a folder with .wav
- a folder with .jpg

And everything is named incrementially like this "video_sc1, video_sc2" "sound_sc1, sound_sc2" etc.

So, is there a possibility to create a lot of .fla file (the same amount as detected in the .flv folder, for example) with all the "corresponding" stuff inside ?
And finally obtaining something like this "animfile_sc01.fla, animfile_sc02.fla ..." without doing all this manually (very boring and time-consuming)

I do some python, and very very little .jsfl, so, I'm not sure about the faisability of my project ( I use flash mainly for animation and graphics, not so much for coding).
Do you have any hint or tip to show me ?

Thanks !
(ps: my english is not perfect, but I can explain better if needed)

Comment: You just need to generate empty files with the correct naming convention, is this correct?

Comment: Not totally empty, the .fla is organized with specific layers with contents inside, and external file imported into the layers.

For example, the file  "animfile_sc02.fla" will contains inside three layers, named "VIDEO" "SOUND" "JPG", and on each corresponding layer, there is a "video_sc02.flv", "sound_sc02.wav" "image_sc02.jpg"


Maybe I can upload a little example if needed.


I have maybe an idea, I'm looking to create .xfl file with python (it's a lot of xml, in fact) and maybe compress/or making .fla from this .xfl

Still testing, if I found something good, I'll tell here :)

Comment: Here is a little visual explanation of what I'm searching to do, maybe much clearer !
http://i.imgur.com/CSm9AOH.jpg

Comment: better give a file as an example.

Comment: Here it is : https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/70c9d0a518a850117b537caadbb0f2a020160908104012/b66940

The kind of .fla file I need to generate is inside /what_we_need/fla/
It is done with Animate CC

Comment: this sounds like something for jsfl, check [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/flash_cs5_extending.pdf), if you edit your post with some screenshots of the file structure & how the fla should be i can help with some code as well

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue.
I suggest you see the structure of a fla.
to do that take one of you fla and save it from animate into a .xfl
It's basically a folder what inside all the library and the content visible.
If you open the DOMDocument.xml you'll see the XML structure of your fla.
If you use visual basic or other software you may be able to "recreate2 a DOMDocument.xml and all the other folder and the rebuild the fla.
It's a b it long g and tricky..but it may works

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use *JSFL* inside of *Flash*. [xJSFL](http://xjsfl.com/) is a pretty popular alternative to *JSFL* that is likely to be better documented and faster to implement.

If this process needs to be part of an on-going build system then check out my updated version of the [flashcommand](https://github.com/haysclark/flashcommand) python script.